# Makefile creation for subdirectories Makefile

Tags: c, linux, shell, makefile, project

I'm new to `Makefile` and I have to create a `Makefile` for my project.

```
project
├── Makefile
|
├── application
│   |── code1
│   |   ├── header-->header1.h(Inside the header1 folder)
│   |   |── source-->main1.c(Inside the source1 folder)
|   |   ├── doc-->Makefile
|   |
|   |── code2
|   |   ├── header-->header2.h(Inside the header2 folder)
|   |   |── source-->main2.c(Inside the source2 folder)
|   |   ├── doc-->Makefile
```

For this **project**, how can I write the `Makefile` for inside the code1 & code2 and the overall one `Makefile`
How to create the overall `Makefile` to run the subdirectories `Makefile`

Comment: Do you have to use a `makefile`? If possible I would recommend to use `cmake` instead.

Comment: Why do you think that you need a Makefile in each directory...?

Comment: I have to use in linux `Makefile`

Comment: @user253751: Then how to run the C programs inside the project folder

Comment: It would be a lot simpler if you used the same subdirectory names inside each directory. Having a `Makefile` in `doc` is outright alien.

Comment: @tripleee: ok, i will change it

Comment: @Yuvi you compile each source file, link the object files, then run the program file. Same as always. Why do you think you need a Makefile in each directory?

Comment: Meson/Ninja makes this easy with `subdirs()`. Just sayin'...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
.PHONY: all
all: application/code1/exe1 application/code2/exe2

application/code1/exe1: application/code1/source/main1.c application/code1/header/header1.c

application/code2/exe2: application/code2/source/main2.c application/code2/header/header2.c
```

The `application/` level adds to the pain here; perhaps you should remove it. Alternatively, maybe put the `Makefile` in `application` and remove the toplevel directories in the above.